# How to display the content of an object inside a view?

Tags: java, html, ajax, view

**To contextualize:**

I'm trying to use AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    url : urlN, // <<- "/log"
    type: "post",
    success : function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = json;
    }

setInterval(refreshDiv, 5000);
```

to update, at each 'X' times, only one part of an HTML page (`<div>`). The problem is that I could not get the contents of my file, because my controller was returning the name of my view, which resulted in this:

[image]

After several attempts, I discovered that I could not pass the view name, but an object of the file I would like to access. Under advice, I added the @ResponseBody notation so that the method return is automatically written in response to the client. But, by doing this, I ended up "losing" my view and the only return displayed was the content itself, sense I can't have two controllers with the same URL. That is, my problem was reversed..

[image]

What I would like to do is, kind of, unite these two exits in one, like:

[image]
Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/log", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
         //String  - View
    public Log jsonLogContent(@Valid Log log, BindingResult bindingResult, Map<String, Object> model) {
        if (log.getInitLine() == 0 && log.getFinalLine() == 0) {
            try {
                fileNumberLines(log);
                log.setPathFile(logsDir + "/" + log.getFilename());
                log.setContent(getLogContentByRange(0, log.getInitLine(), log.getFinalLine(), log.getPathFile()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            log.setContent(getLogContentByRange(0, log.getInitLine(), log.getFinalLine(), logsDir + "/" + log.getFilename()));
        }

        // view
        model.put("path", logsDir);
        model.put("log", log);
        model.put("currentPage", "logs");
        model.put("root", root);
       //return "log"; - View

        return log;    // Obj
    }
```

So, **my question is:**

How can I do this? How do I get my to view loaded first,and then load the object into it? I ask this, because, no matter what I do, the only thing that is being displayed, with the @ResponseBody notation, is the contents of the file.